# Why is the Continuity of the Constant, Linear and Identity Functions not Proved with the Definition of Continuity

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

All of the proofs that I have seen for the constant, identity and linear functions use the delta-epsilon definition of a limit to prove their continuity. How can this constitute a proof for continuity if it only proves the existence of a limit at $c$ but not that the function is defined at those points.

[Consider Paul Dawkin's notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitProofs.aspx#Extras_Limit_LimitProp)

I am probably missing something, could someone explain to me why delta epsilon proofs are used rather than using the definition of continuity, $\forall \epsilon > 0\; \exists\: \delta > 0|\; |x-c| <\delta \rightarrow|f(x)-f(c)| <\epsilon$

Comment: But that *is* the definition of continuity.  Writing out the $\delta-\epsilon$ proof verifies the definition.  Note that the definition contains the term $f(c)$, so the function is definitely defined at the point $x=c$.

Comment: I wrote the definition of continuity at the bottom of the post, but the proofs do not use that definition.

Comment: Sure they do.  The definition (Definition 9 at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfLimit.aspx) is exactly the same thing as checking that $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$.

Comment: Oh, I guess you are missing the following. For a function defined on some interval(say) containing the point $c$, it is continuous at $c$ iff $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = f(c)$.

Comment: @Randall If you check the proofs for the limit properties, it is clear that the epsilon delta definition of a limit is being used rather than the definition of continuity. E.g. When proving the continuity of the linear functions or constant function.

Comment: Right, but he isn't checking continuity. He is showing that certain limit laws hold.  As a **consequence**, one of those limit laws verifies the continuity of $f(x)=x$.

Comment: The definition of continuity depends on the definition of the limit which depends on epsilon/delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function being continuous in a point $c$ is equivalent to the following equality:
$$
  f(c) = \lim_{x \to c} f(x).
$$
This means that if you wish to prove that $f$ is continuous in some point, you can simply prove that the limit exists and is equal to the value of the function.

To show this equivalence, first we have the epsilon delta definition of a limit: If the following holds, then we say $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$.
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0,\exists \ \delta > 0 \text{ such that } 0 < |x - c | < \delta \ \Rightarrow \ |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon
$$
But this is exactly your definition of continuity, just with $f(c)$ in place of $L$.

Comment: Except the definition of continuity has $|x-c|<\delta$ as the hypothesis to force the function to behave correctly at $x=c$ (otherwise removable discontinuities become continuities).

Comment: @Randall fair enough, the definitions are different in that regard, however since $0 = |x - c|$ always implies $|f(x) - f(c)| = 0$, which is smaller than any $\varepsilon$, the definition with $0 < |x - c|$ is equivalent to the one without.

Comment: They are definitely not equivalent, as the version with $0 < |x-c|$ never says anything about what happens at $x=c$.  That's why the continuity version either must have $0 \leq |x-c| < \delta$ or (equivalently) also demand that the limit at $c$ be equal to $f(c)$.

Comment: If there's a removable discontinuity at $c$, the definition with $0 < |x - c|$ will have the limit $L$ be something else than $f(c)$, but as I said in the answer, we have $f(c)$ in place of $L$, thus adding the requirement you also mention that the limit at $c$ is equal to $f(c)$.